# Unit Testing Entity Framework Validation

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, validation

I have written some custom validation for some Entity Framework objects using IValidatableObject and I have added some DataAnnotations to the objects for validation.

I wanted to test that validation is meeting the required validation (ensuring that the custom validation is working and that any changes made keep those Data Annotations etc...) but I can't determine how to run the validation in the unit test without calling SaveChanges (which I don't want to do as if there is an issue and validation doesn't work it would write to the data source)

I wanted to do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void InvalidStartDate_StartDateAfterEndDate()
{
   var header = new Header()
                    {
                        StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
                        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)
                    };
   var actual = header.IsValid();
   var expected = false;
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Or something like

```
[TestMethod]
public void InvalidStartDate_StartDateAfterEndDate()
{
   var header = new Header()
                    {
                        StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
                        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)
                    };
   var actual = header.GetValidationErrors().Count;
   var expected = 0;
   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

But can't seem to find a way of getting the validation to run without calling save changes, is there a way to do this?

Comment: db.GetValidationErrors() should work.. can you post the code for your Header class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can invoke the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator) to validate the object.

```
[TestMethod]
public void InvalidStartDate_StartDateAfterEndDate()
{
   var header = new Header()
                    {
                        StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
                        EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15)
                    };

   var context = new ValidationContext(header, null, null);
   var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

   var actual = Validator.TryValidateObject(header, context, results);
   var expected = false;

   Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: There's a fourth parameter on TryValidateObject which is a boolean responsible for iterate over all properties even those that don't have Required as an attribute - if you left it out, some validations won't happen. @Eranga, it'd be nice if you could update your answer to include it, thanks!