# How to clear Validation Results in an Entity Framework Object

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, validation

It is possible to clear the Validation Results in an ObjectContext associated with an Entity Framework? What I wanted is something like this code:

```
public void ClearValidationResults (ObjectContext db)
{
        var dbContext = new DbContext(db, true);

        var validationResults = dbContext.GetValidationErrors();

        validationResults.Clear();
}
```

I want to implement this functionality to use in unit tests to test the validation rules without to have to save changes in DataBase.
Thanks.

Comment: You can also use the [Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx) class to validate objects and entities? I think that is easier, than using the ObjectContext for validation. Also does the ObjectContext use the Validator internally for validation of DataAnnotations.

Comment: I already try the Validator class with no success. You can see my problem with Validator here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767295/unit-testing-for-entity-framework-validation>.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I resolve the problem by creating a new ObjectContext object every time I need to clear the validation errors. Is not the most elegant solution but it works. Since this process is in the context of unit tests and the unit tests are fast enough, I will maintain this code until best solution arrived.

```
public void ClearValidationResults (ObjectContext db)
{
    db =  new MyObjectContext();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`DbContext` does not store validation errors, it validates entities each time you call `DbContext.GetValidationErrors()` or `DbContext.SaveChanges()`. So, if you have an invalid entity that is being tracked by your context `DbContext.GetValidationErrors()` will always return errors. You need to detach or fix the invalid entity/entities and the error will go away since there will be no invalid entities tracked by your context.

Answer (score 4):

**Clear Entity Local Storage.**

When we adding Entity to Collection, its adding it to its Local Storage and we kept getting errors as the Local Storage of that Entity is not clear and still having old entries. So you Clear Entity Local rows.

```
dbContext.EntityName.Local.Clear();
```

Comment: Since I’m using ObjectContext, and not dbContext, I can’t use the Local property. So, that solution is not useful in this context.

Comment: would give u 1000000 up but am limited to 1